# MongoDB is not responding

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu

I have been searching for why this has been happening, but recently I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 and I copied a Node + Express project to a flash drive then pasted it to the exact same corresponding location (~/Programming/project/). Upon doing that, everything else works as I would expect but Mongo is not responding when I make requests to it through Mongoose. I do not have any reason to believe that Mongoose is the reason for the failure to respond. I have a couple of routes in which I know should work, the exact same code works on my friend's machine (same Ubuntu, version and everything). I have uninstalled and reinstalled everything (Including Ubuntu) multiple times. The only thing that works is making a call to find something with a specific ID will return if and only if the ID does not exist. Mongo won't return all the records or anything else. The website just spins endlessly (locally hosted on my machine). However, using Mongo in the terminal works fine. I can query and get results as if everything is normal. Has this happened to anyone else or is there any ideas? I can try to include some code.

This does not work

```
        Greeting.find({}, function(err, greetings) {
          res.status(200).json(greetings);
        });
```

This does work.

```
Greeting.findById(req.params.id, function(err, greeting) {
  if(err)
    res.status(404).json({"error": "Greeting with that ID does not exist"});

  res.status(200).json(greeting);
});
```

EDIT:
Sorry, I am new to stack overflow so I am still getting the hang of what should be added or not...

```
mongoose.connect(database.url);
mongoose.connection.on('error', function() {
 console.info("Could not run mongodb, did you forget to run mongod?");
});
```

The database.url is what it needs to be, the connection is open as far as I can tell...

I should also mention that while installing Ubuntu, I wiped my previous dual boot in favor of just having Ubuntu, and so I opted in for the hard-drive encryption... Could that be preventing Mongo from working properly? If so, how would I fix that?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling mongoose.connect with the correct connection string?

Comment: @Paul Yes, I will add that in a little bit, but the connection opens fine as far as I can tell

Comment: @Paul I have added the database connection, I think it works fine from what I can tell

Comment: @DraganS Doing it before the 'if(err)'  and after the 'Greeting.findById...' never comes up. Doing it before the 'Greeting.findById...' works as expected.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Could you try this:
console.log('Here');
Greeting.find({}, function(err, greetings) {
          if(err) console.log('err', err);
          res.status(200).json(greetings);
        });

Comment: @DraganS It's all good. I tried that and "Here" console.logs, no error console.logs and no results come back. Eventually the browser gives up and sends another request.

Comment: I would try with `console.log('greetings', greetings)` or `greetings = [{id:1, text: 'test'}]; res.status(200).json...` in order to check the response from the db or server, as well as to log the count `Greeting.count((err, count) => ...)` :)

Comment: @DraganS console.log('greetings', greetings);... Never prints anything and Greeting.count((err, count) => ..); never comes back either. I am really frustrated that for whatever reason mongo decides to just not work all the sudden. Thank you for trying to help me though

Comment: If the whole block  is replaced to `res.json({hi: 'there'})`, did you get the json response?

Comment: @DraganS I do not, it is like the Mongo server never returns or gets the call

Comment: Try this `console.log('Here'); /* Greeting.find({}, function(err, greetings) {
          res.status(200).json(greetings);
        }); */
        res.json({hi: 'there'})`
just to check the end point (I presume that Express is used)

Comment: @DraganS Works like a charm without the database call. I'm gonna nuke my hard drive and reinstall without the disk encryption this time. I'm determined that is the only thing I have yet to try. It'll probably take me an hour but I'll let you know how it goes when I'm finished.

Comment: Before you do that, it's strange that `Greeting.findById` works. How about node-debug? (https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27#.obtgnpaie)

Comment: @DraganS I found that FindbyID only worked before the collection was populated.. The error was that there were no records. Reinstalling fixed it! The encrypted hard drive apparently is a problem. If you want to post an answer just saying to reinstall and that the encryption was messing with the DB I'll choose your answer (not that there are any others) Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Glad that you fixed it. Check out this tool: https://robomongo.org

Comment: @DraganS That's awesome! Thank you for showing me, I have been looking for a tool to be like the myAdmin portal with MySQL servers but for mongo!

Comment: Check Docker for Mac. Install, `docker pull mongo:last` and check the page `https://github.com/dockerfile/mongodb`. [If you have a local instance of mongoDB, just change the port (-d)], execute `docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mongodb dockerfile/mongodb` and enjoy :)

Comment: I got it set up and it is very nice! I'll definitely be using it for the future to visualize the data! Thanks so much! @DraganS

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in fact the encrypted hard drive. I reinstalled Ubuntu and that fixed it. I'm still not sure how to make it work with an encrypted disk.